# Docker not restarting and building

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I stopped my celery using

```
docker-compose stop celery
```

But when I try to start it again and check ps it's not restarting

```
docker-compose ps

radar_celery_1     celery worker -l info -A r ...   Exit 1                                               
radar_data_1       true                             Restarting                                           
radar_nginx_1      /usr/sbin/nginx                  Up           0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                      
radar_postgres_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up           5432/tcp                                
radar_rabbitmq_1   docker-entrypoint.sh rabbi ...   Up           25672/tcp, 4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 5672/tcp 
radar_radar_1      bash -c /usr/local/bin/gun ...   Up           0.0.0.0:8002->8000/tcp                  
radar_redis_1      docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up           6379/tcp
```

and when I try building it again, there's a message error

```
docker-compose up
Attaching to radar_celery_1
celery_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
celery_1    |     sys.exit(main())
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
celery_1    |     main()
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
celery_1    |     cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 793, in execute_from_commandline
celery_1    |     super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 311, in execute_from_commandline
celery_1    |     return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 785, in handle_argv
celery_1    |     return self.execute(command, argv)
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 717, in execute
celery_1    |     ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 179, in run_from_argv
celery_1    |     return self(*args, **options)
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 274, in __call__
celery_1    |     ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 212, in run
celery_1    |     state_db=self.node_format(state_db, hostname), **kwargs
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
celery_1    |     self.app.loader.init_worker()
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 128, in init_worker
celery_1    |     self.import_default_modules()
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 116, in import_default_modules
celery_1    |     signals.import_modules.send(sender=self.app)
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/dispatch/signal.py", line 166, in send
celery_1    |     response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/utils.py", line 42, in __call__
celery_1    |     self.set_error_state(exc)
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/utils.py", line 39, in __call__
celery_1    |     **dict(self.kwargs, **kwargs) if self.kwargs else kwargs
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 330, in _autodiscover_tasks
celery_1    |     self.loader.autodiscover_tasks(packages, related_name)
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 252, in autodiscover_tasks
celery_1    |     related_name) if mod)
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 273, in autodiscover_tasks
celery_1    |     return [find_related_module(pkg, related_name) for pkg in packages]
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 299, in find_related_module
celery_1    |     return importlib.import_module('{0}.{1}'.format(package, related_name))
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
celery_1    |     __import__(name)
celery_1    |   File "/usr/src/app/provider/GG/tasks.py", line 30, in <module>
celery_1    |     class GGFetchBR(PeriodicSet, PeriodicTask):
celery_1    |   File "/usr/src/app/provider/GG/tasks.py", line 47, in GGFetchBR
celery_1    |     time = json.loads(config_parser.get('GG', 'time'))
celery_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 618, in get
celery_1    |     raise NoOptionError(option, section)
celery_1    | ConfigParser.NoOptionError: No option 'time' in section: 'GG'
radar_celery_1 exited with code 1
```

I tried it running it, but this is the response

```
(radar) Deans-MacBook-Pro:ci-radar deanchristianarmada$ docker exec -it radar_celery_1 bash
Error response from daemon: Container 358de1322d8ac62c8307ac704e02d03454eb79fbdd9ad44d57365c0978920658 is not running
```

So, how do I resolve this? I wish to fix the one that causes the error on my python file

Comment: You can force to re-create with "docker-compose build --force-recreate"

Comment: I'm guessing that doing this will create every image.. Is it possible to just recreate on my celery image?

Comment: Unfortunately recreate did not work

Comment: Last option should be to remove all containers and volumes and redo building

Comment: It is clear that the image used for radar_celery is not working. This `radar_celery_1     celery worker -l info -A r ...   Exit 1 ` shows that that container never started well and instead did exit with error code 1.  When you run docker-compose or docker stop and the service you should see exit code = 0

Comment: Actually, I already solved it and posted my answer on how I solved it

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it, by copying the files to that container. So it is possible to copy files even though the container is not running

1.) check first the container id, use -a to see all containers even those not running

```
docker ps -a
```

2.) copy the file that needs change

```
docker-compose cp file <container_id>:/the/path/to/file
```

3.) Try starting or building the image again